# I can't update select multiple options in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

**Controller**

[image]

**Here is my select option**

[image]

The database only saves the last value. Please, I need help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add multiple values to a single column try one to many.
Maintain a other table for skills and link the both with user id or try converting skills data to json and then save it(it may be intimidating sometimes)